# Question about mean squared error of a sum raised to the kth power

Tags: probability, expected-value, error

Let
\begin{equation}
Q = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i 
\end{equation}
be a sum that we want to estimate. Let us suppose we have an algorithm $\mathcal{A}$, outputting an estimate $\hat Q$, such that
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[(Q - \hat Q)^{2}] = \beta,
\end{equation}
where the expectation is taken over the randomness of the algorithm.

Now, consider the quantity $Q^{k}$ for an integer $k$.

We run $\mathcal{A}$ to get $\hat Q$ and output $\hat Q^{k}$ as an estimate for $Q^{k}$. Can we bound the quantity
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[(Q^{k} - \hat Q^{k})^{2}],
\end{equation}
in terms of $\beta$ --- where the expectation is again taken over the randomness of the algorithm?

I think it should be more than $\beta^{k}$ but I could not prove it.

For simplicity, take each $\alpha_i$ to be between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: For some distributions, and $k$ large enough,\begin{equation}\mathbb{E}[(Q^{k} - \hat Q^{k})^{2}],\end{equation}is infinite, so there is no hope in finding a general relation.

Comment: What might be an example of such a distribution?

Comment: Any Student t distribution.  Any Pareto distribution.